# Alert Component doesn't re-fire second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've created an Alert component to be able to send alerts from all components in a ReactJS app, passing it through a Context.Provider. The messages, are stored in a state, and the state function is passed as the value for the Context.Provider.

However, if I try to use it once it works, but the second time it doesn't. Any ideas?

Alert.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
`;

const Alert = ({ message }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      setVisible(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setVisible(false);
      }, 5000);
    }
  },[message]);
  if (visible) {
    return <StyledDiv id="alert">{message}</StyledDiv>;
  } else return null;
};
export default Alert;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import Alert from "./components/alert/Alert";
export const AlertContext = createContext();
function App() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <Alert message={alert} />
      <AlertContext.Provider value={setAlert}>
       COMPONENTS HERE
      </AlertContext.Provider>
   </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: where do you update the message props?

Comment: I use a useConext(Context.Provider) on my child components to work it.

Comment: weird, the useEffect should be triggered everytime the message is updated.

Comment: btw, how do you update the message? is that a string?

Comment: I use it mostly for error messaging, throught catch(e => setAlert(e.message)).

Comment: did you try console inside the useEffect when you update the message?

Comment: Yes I tried that, mounts once, then unmounts, then doesn't mount again.

Comment: you should check the useEffect, remove the dependency and try console.log(message) to see what happens when it is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

just put the message as a param in your useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      setVisible(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
      setVisible(false);
    }, 5000);
   }
}, [ message ]);
```

That way it will actr everytime the message changes.

Comment: Tried it, it won't re-render. I actually tried this before.

Answer (score 1):

useEffect takes two arguments. The first is a function, the second is an array. The function fires any time an element in the array changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      setVisible(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setVisible(false);
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [ messsage ]);
```

Comment: I know what you mean, this is what I did at first. Still won't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is happening because you don't clear the `setTimeout`. Try something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = null;
    if (message) {
      setVisible(true);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
         setVisible(false);
      }, 5000);
    }

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [message]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to cleanup after the useEffect! But still it won't work.

Comment: hmm ok. If you try to log the message inside useEffect, can you see it the second time?

Comment: I tried looking into it like this. It just fires first time, then unmounts. then doesn't mount again.

Comment: is the error the same when you expect to see the message again or is a different error? If the error message is the same, you will not see the alert again, since the message is the same. What about if you set the message as null inside the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the state in the App.js was not updating, so I sent it as a prop to the Alert component to update it there.

Alert.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
`;

const Alert = ({ setAlert, message }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (message) {
      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setAlert(null);
      }, 5000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [message]);
  if (message) {
    return <StyledDiv id="alert">{message}</StyledDiv>;
  } else return null;
};
export default Alert;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import Alert from "./components/alert/Alert";
export const AlertContext = createContext();
function App() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState();
  return (
    <>
      <Alert setAlert={setAlert} message={alert} />
      <AlertContext.Provider value={setAlert}>
       COMPONENTS HERE
      </AlertContext.Provider>
   </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Everyone that helped. Thanks a lot, your input was invaluable.